# SVMs: the distance from a point to the decision boundary

Tags: svm

I came across this diagram while learning the derivation for SVMs:

[image]

The author makes the claim that $\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}_{\perp} + r\frac{\textbf{w}}{||\textbf{w}||}$, where $r$ is the distance from **x** to the decision boundary. The decision boundary for binary classification is defined through $f(\textbf{x})=\textbf{w}^\textbf{T}\textbf{x} + w_0$.

I don't understand this; shouldn't this be defined as $\textbf{x} = \textbf{x}_{\perp} + r\frac{\textbf{w}}{||\textbf{w}||} + (\frac{-w_0}{||\textbf{w}||})(\frac{\textbf{w}}{||\textbf{w}||})$? That is to say, in the original equation, should't $r$ also include the distance $\frac{-w_0}{||\textbf{w}||}$? The projection of **x** on the decision boundary should be represented by the black leftmost diagonal vector, no?

Comment: Could you clarify?  I don't see anything I would characterize as a "black diagonal vector."  I see two black vectors and they form the *legs* of a right triangle.  I also see two other vector-like symbols but they appear to denote coordinate directions.

Comment: Apologies, edited. I meant it to be the black diagonal vector that isn't labeled with a value.

Comment: Assuming the decision boundary is the red line, the projection of $x$ onto it is not explicitly shown, but corresponds to the point where the dotted blue vector intersects the red line.  Because $w_0$ is not defined or explained anywhere, I hesitate even to try to interpret this diagram.  Isn't $w_0$ supposed to be a vector?  A multiple of it, $-w_0/||w||,$ appears to be labeling a two-headed "vector" in the diagram, whatever that's intended to mean.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the decision boundary equation. I think $w_0$ is just the intercept.

Comment: In that case the labels $-w_0/||w||$ and $r$ refer to signed distances, rather than to vectors themselves.